# How to set page counter in mdframed as footer?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am using mdframed as footer and want page number as footer but in mdframed. If i use mdframed it overwrites on page number. How can i write page number in footer within mdframed?

[image]

EDIT: Code of the comment

```
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=4pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=blue,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=5,innertopmargin=5,innerbottommargin=5,everyline = true, splittopskip=.6cm, splitbottomskip=.3cm] 
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright{ID} \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering{footertext} \parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft{Date} \end{mdframed}}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{lipsum} 
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[C]{% 
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue!60,roundcorner=3pt] 
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright XXXXXXXX}% 
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering Page}% 
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft 31 July 2012} 
\end{mdframed}% 
} 
\begin{document} 
\lipsum[1-2] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide a complete working document in your question, for example the one that generated that image, so people answering know what to start from.

Comment: I m using code below.
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{mdframed}[roundcorner=4pt,leftmargin=1, rightmargin=1, linecolor=blue,outerlinewidth=.5, innerleftmargin=5,innertopmargin=5,innerbottommargin=5,everyline = true, splittopskip=.6cm, splitbottomskip=.3cm]
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright{ID}
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering{footertext}
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft{Date}
\end{mdframed}}

Comment: I get unrelated tex errors trying to do anything with that fragment. Please edit _the question_ to have a _complete_ example starting with `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{%
\begin{mdframed}[linecolor=blue!60,roundcorner=3pt]
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedright XXXXXXXX}%
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering Page}%
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\raggedleft 31 July 2012}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{document}  Above code is for generating footer text but i need page number. How can i implement it?

Comment: Use the more exact `\dimexpr\textwidth/3\relax` instead of `0.333\textwidth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `\thepage`

```
\parbox[t]{0.333\textwidth}{\centering Page \thepage}%
```

Please in future always put complete documents *in the question* (as I edited your question this time) it makes answering the question so much easier.

Comment: My first page is title page so i don't need numbering on first page. For that i am using \thispagestyle{empty}. But I need counter should start from next page which means nextpage will be having page 1 and so on. How can i implement it?