# How to set page counter by skipping first page?

Tags: page-numbering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No page numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54333/no-page-numbering)

I am working on numbering on page. I already got reply for my previous question.

[How to set page counter in mdframed as footer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65565/how-to-set-page-counter-in-mdframed-as-footer)

But i want to skip first page as it is title page. So i m using \thispagestyle{empty}. But next page start from 2. Page after title should be marked as page 1 since title page is not counted. How can i implement it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No page numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54333/5764).

Answer (score 93, accepted):

After the title page, put

```
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

This is ok if you are using `oneside` option. But for `two  side` document, it is better to `\cleardoublepage` as noted by @Ulrike Fischer in the comment.

Comment: `\cleardoublepage` is better, as it will avoid troubles if you use a `twoside` class. Also the code will give warnings if `hyperref` is used. For possible work arounds see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18924/pdftex-warning-ext4-destination-with-the-same-identifier-nam-epage-1-has.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks for noting. I did not know the details of OP's file structure (as there is no MWE), hence I adopted a lazy way. Now I added a note in the answer as per your comment.