# Prevent title page from being considered as page "1"

Tags: pdf, titles, page-numbering, viewers

I am write a big document use `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` to get different page numbering for different parts. All is fine except that the title page appears to be page 1; that is, there are two page 1 (the other is page 1 of the mainmatter). Two page 1 causes a problem for printing: if I want to print page 1 to 3, then Adobe Reader will print from the title page to the page 3 in the mainmatter.

Addendum: I am not ask not print the page 1 on the title page. I want to make sure that Adobe Reader can figure out page 1 is not the title page but page 1 in the mainmatter.

I think the problem is `hyperref`, without it the viewer will count page numbers plainly.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{This is a book}
\author{Zero}
\date{2014}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\section*{Preface} \lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First section} \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second section} \lipsum[2]
\chapter{Last section} \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54333/no-page-numbering and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66562/how-to-set-page-counter-by-skipping-first-page

Comment: @remjg I think my question is different. I clarified a little above. The solutions there do not work for my purpose.

Comment: @MaMing Then please provide a MWE that we can fiddle with ;)

Comment: I’d say the title page should be part of the front matter an thus get the number `i` …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add for instance `\pagenumbering{alph}` before `\maketitle` -- the first two pages will become `a`, `b` and no confusion of Acrobat can appear:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{This is a book}
\author{Zero}
\date{2014}
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\maketitle

\frontmatter

\section*{Preface} \lipsum[1]
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{First section} \lipsum[1]
\chapter{Second section} \lipsum[2]
\chapter{Last section} \lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

However, as Tobi points out, the correct approach is to include the titlepage in the front matter.