# Numbering this special equation

Tags: numbering

I have some problems. I attache the Tex file for you. I didn't put nember in first page, but the second page started from 2  and the passages are untidy in pdf (not left to right as the same way I wrote in Latex file).

In the second page I want to nymber the second equation by 2.1  and 2.2, but I cannot number it. Also the third equation should has label 3...

Help me please.

```
‎\begin{document}‎
\begin{center}‎
‎\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{1.jpg}‎
‎\end{center}‎
‎\begin{center}‎
\textbf{Department of Mechanical Engineering}\\ 
‎\vspace{1.5cm}‎
\textbf{Fluid Mechanics}\\
‎\vspace{1.5cm}‎
\textit{Report Title: ‎}\\‎
\textbf{Laminar Flow ‎}\\‎
‎\vspace{1.5cm}‎
‎%\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{zia.jpg}\\‎
Student: \textbf{Zia Daghighi}\\
‎\vspace{1cm}‎
Teacher: \textbf{Nouroz}
‎\end{center}‎‎‎
‎\thispagestyle{empty}‎
‎\newpage‎‎‎
\begin{equation}
 at \,\,\‎, ‎r^{*}=1‎: ‎\,\,\,\,\‎, ‎T_{1}^{*}=0
\end{equation}
‎\[‎
‎at \,\,\‎, ‎r^{*}=\phi:\,\,\,\,\‎, ‎\begin{cases}‎
‎T_{1}^{*}= T_{2}^{*}  \\‎
‎\\‎
‎\frac{\partial T_{1}^{*}}{\partial r^{*}}=\frac {\partial T_{2}^{*}}{\partial r^{*}}‎
‎\end{cases}‎
‎\]‎
‎\\‎
‎\[‎
‎\begin{vmatrix}‎
‎F_{1}(1) & F_{2}(1) & 0\\‎
‎F_{1}(\phi) & F_{2}(\phi) &‎ -‎F_{3}(\phi) \\‎
‎F^{'}_{1}(\phi) & F^{'}_{2}(\phi) &‎ -‎F^{'}_{3}(\phi)‎
‎\end{vmatrix}=0‎
‎\]‎

‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In the nature of this Q&A site lies that we normally only ask one question per ... eh .. question. For your first question see [How to set page counter by skipping first page?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66562/35864) and [No page numbering](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54333/35864). For your unnumbered equations you use `\[...\]` which does not number by default, use `\begin{equation}.\end{equation}`/`\begin{align}.\end{align}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[subnum]{cases}

\begin{document}‎
\begin{equation}
    \text{at } r^{*}=1‎: \quad ‎T_{1}^{*}=0
\end{equation}
\begin{numcases}{\text{at } r^{*}=\phi:\quad}
    ‎T_{1}^{*}= T_{2}^{*}  \\‎
    \frac{\partial T_{1}^{*}}{\partial r^{*}}=\frac {\partial T_{2}^{*}}{\partial r^{*}}‎
\end{numcases}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{vmatrix}‎
        ‎F_{1}(1)     & F_{2}(1)     & 0                \\‎
        ‎F_{1}(\phi)  & F_{2}(\phi)  &‎ -‎F_{3}(\phi)     \\‎
        ‎F'_{1}(\phi) & F'_{2}(\phi) &‎ -‎F'_{3}(\phi) ‎
    \end{vmatrix}=0‎
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]